# How to do language translation in php echo call when parameter is a variable

Tags: php, wordpress, echo

I've inherited a wordpress plugin where the a variable holds the value of the html string to be displayed.

For example,

```
$html=$html."<H1>Enter Your Account Information </h1>";
$html=$html."<h2>Your First Name</h2>";
$html=$html.  .... (more strings like above)  ....
echo $html
```

The whole plugin has this type of construct, where instead of

```
 echo '<H1>Enter Your Account Information </h1>';
```

which can easily be changed to:

```
echo '<h1>' . __('Enter Your Account Information', 'myplugin') . '</h1>';
```

Is there a way to do the translation the way it's currently implemented?

Or do I have to change it so that it echos to the screen immediately and skip building the $html variable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the String with translation like

```
$html .= '<h1>' . __('Enter Your Account Information', 'myplugin') . '</h1>';
$html .= '<h2>' . __('Your First Name', 'myplugin') . '</h2>';
```

later on you can `echo` the `$html` variable like

```
echo $html;
```

---

**Note:** If you want to echo the translation immediately just use:

```
 _e('Enter Your Account Information', 'myplugin');
```